# passing argument to model method with grape-entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-grape, grape-api

How can I pass an argument to a model method using grape entity ?

I'd like to check wheter the current_user likes an item when presenting the item, so I built a model `user_likes?` method:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  #some attributes here...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :likers

  def user_likes?(user)
    likers.include?(user)
  end
end
```

but I don't know how to send current_user to the grape-entity model :

```
module FancyApp
  module Entities
    class Item < Grape::Entity
      expose :name #easy
      expose :user_likes # <= How can I send an argument to this guy ?
    end 
  end
end
```

in the grape api:

```
get :id do
  item = Item.find(.....)
  present item, with: FancyApp::Entities::Item # I should probably send current_user here, but how ?
end
```

I feel like the current_user should probably be sent from this last piece of code, but I can't figure how to do it :(

Any thoughts ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found I could pass `current` as a parameters, and use it in a block. So :

```
present item, with: FancyApp::Entities::Item, :current_user => current_user
```

and in the entity definition:

```
expose :user_likes do |item,options|
  item.user_likes?(options[:current_user])
end
```

Comment: It might let you do it, doesn't mean it's the best way though. Cleaner the way I suggested.

Comment: @Oliver Barnes I'm new to Grape entities can you elaborate on how your suggestion is cleaner? It seems to me, in your suggestion, you are altering the actual record in the database just to pass it to the entity, this doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: I'd actually recommand NOT to use `update_attributes` in any case. It does indeed perform a database altering, and you absolutely do NOT want that. If two users simultaneously request your route, then you'd have a great chance of mixing the `current_user` value for at least one of the users.

Comment: True, don't know what I was thinking. Answered in a haste probably - deleted

Answer (score 0):

@aherve, for some reason your syntax won't work in my case. The syntax in [Grape Entity docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/grape-entity/Grape/Entity#content) is a little different

your example, the syntax should be:

```
expose(:user_likes) { |item, options| item.user_likes?(options[:current_user]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to store the current user in the item temporarily by defining an attribute accessor:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  #some attributes here...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :likers
  attr_accessor :current_user

  def user_likes
    likers.include?(current_user)
  end
end
```

and in the grape api set the current user:

```
get :id do
  item = Item.find(.....)
  item.current_user = current_user
  present item, with: FancyApp::Entities::Item
end
```

no changes to the grape-entity model is needed.
There is no database field `current_user_id` or so. No writes to database.